# Make background image of containing div show over background image of child div?

Tags: css, background-image

Is it possible to make the background image of a containing div show over the background image of a child div?

If I add a border to the parent div that does show over the child's background image, but a background image applied to the parent does not.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have so far? It's not entirely clear.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to achieve the impossible to be honest. Child divs display inside and on top of parent divs, that's how the box model works. Maybe describe the effect you're trying to achieve and we can help you find another way?

Comment: The border seems to be on top, but the div will just clip anything that doesn't fit between the borders. What you want in impossible. Just can just use a separate child not that you position above the other child node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it seems this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you'd want to do that but the only solution i can see is to use css `z-index` to put the child `div` behind the parent

Comment: i think you need to set position on the element if you want to use z-index http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: I dont think the z-index can override the order of elements if they are within each other.

Comment: could be right i cant say for certain you'll have to test it out - sorry

Comment: OK. I did a test and I dont think its possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of effect you are going for, you can most likely use some css to mimic such an effect.

Have you tried using:

```
div.transparent
   {
   background-image:"imageLocation.jpg"

   /* for IE */
   filter:alpha(opacity=60);
   /* CSS3 standard */
   opacity:0.6;
   }
```

Then just `<div class="transparent">` for your div.

The opacity property effects everything in the `<div>`. However, I think you can override it by adding another class with opacity 1.0 for your content.

Just a thought.